# Autodetect local server with ESP8266

Tags: c++, networking, lua, arduino, esp8266

I have an ESP8266 module (particularly, Cactus Micro r2), which is able to connect to local network and then communicate with my local server via HTTP protocol. However, I have to provide the network SSID, password and the IP address of my server.

Is is possible for the ESP module to send a HTTP broadcast to the whole network with a particular header? And then, the server recognizing the header would respond, thus its IP address would be detected automatically? If not with HTTP, is it achievable with UDP? And is there a communication pattern for the client and server to discover each other?

The only solution (or rather a work-around) I have invented so far, is to iterate through the whole address range of a local subnet (which is usually 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254) and try to initiate communication. However, this is extremely slow  (if the server's IP address is in the upper half of the range). Plus, it will not work on 10.0.0.0 network (not to mention pure IPv6 networks...).

Comment: You need a DNS server to resolve name -> IP address. And of course, the server needs to be registered on the DNS. You could of course cheat and keep a record of the "last known address", and then start from that address next time.  But DNS is the "right" solution.

Comment: That is even worse :D Is there, at least, the option to get all used IP addresses? Something like the 'arp -a' command in  Windows command prompt? This would significantly reduce the number of iterated IP addresses...

Comment: `arp -a` just tracks what IP/mac addresses has talked to your machine (or your machine has talked to). If it doesn't "know" the server, then it probably hasn't talked to it either.

Comment: Yes, but the list of other machines can be filled by broadcasting the ping (or pinging the whole local network via 192.168.1.255)... So, could a system like that be simulated?

Comment: Well, that's more or less the same thing isn't it. What is the ACTUAL problem you are trying to solve? The problem has been solved by inventing DNS, so you're obviously trying to solve that problem in a different way, which typically means "you're doing it wrong".

Comment: No, it was not. The ESP module should be able to connect to a particular server (using the special header) in ANY local network, not just mine. The system should make the module more user friendly. Requiring the users to configure a DNS server at first makes the exact opposite... that is why I am convinced that "doing it wrong" is the right way, in my case.

Comment: "Finding a server" requires some sort of registry to query for the server - it is commonly DNS, but you could of course invent your own, but it still involves KNOWING "who to ask" (the DNS server, or whatever). If there is no registry you will end up scanning the entire network until you find what you are looking for (and hopefully there isn't another one "before" the one you actually want). Alternatively, you could rely on DHCP to give the same address to the server (which often works), and just "scan" first time on a new network. Or, you could register the IP of the ESP in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your esp to find a ***dedicated server*** in any private network without requiring DNS and other setup this can be an answer:

1. On the server side, implement a udp broadcast. This broadcasts the connection information of itself between some intervals (e.g. 2 sec). This is like wifi beaconing (or bluetooth advertising).
2. On the esp side esp must know ssid. Then connect to the network. Start listening the broadcast port for a ***spesific*** message.
3. Upon receiving the message, parse it and verify (authenticate etc.) then get the parameters from the message, which shows the server.
4. Finally use the parameters to communicate with the server and turn off the broadcast listener.